# CSV.foreach Memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My import speed is slow, it takes 2.5 hours to process a 13K line CSV file.

I am wondering why my memory usage keeps going up, as I increase the file size?
I am using `foreach`, so I thought memory usage should be maxed out at the size of each batch import(500 lines at a time). I am trying to process a large 20K line CSV file quickly and with minimal memory usage.

Is there a better way to do this?

Ruby: 2.6.1

Rails 5.2.2

Gem Activerecord-import

#### Code

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'

def print_memory_usage
  memory_before = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i
  yield
  memory_after = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i

  puts "Memory: #{((memory_after - memory_before) / 1024.0).round(2)} MB"
end

def print_time_spent
  time = Benchmark.realtime do
    yield
  end

  puts "Time: #{time.round(2)}"
end

nol = 0
ac = Profile.count
lc = Course.count
fc = Book.count

print_memory_usage do
  print_time_spent do
    i = 0
    profiles = []

    CSV.foreach( File.join(Rails.root, 'lib','sample_data', 'sample.csv'), headers: true) do |row|
      nol+=1
      i+=1

      a = Profile.new(user_id: 1)
      l = a.build_course
      f = a.build_book

      l.name = 'TEST-small sample.csv'
      l.course_name  = row[0]
      a.grade = row[1]
      f.book_title = row[3]

      profiles << a

      if i == 500
        puts "Import Stats"
        print_memory_usage do
          print_time_spent do
            Profile.import profiles, recursive: true
          end
        end

        i=0
        profiles=[]
        puts "--Record Count--"
        puts "Profile: #{ac}/#{Profile.count}"
        puts "Course: #{lc}/#{Course.count}"
        puts "Book: #{fc}/#{Book.count}"
      end
    end
    Profile.import profile, recursive: true
    puts "-- TOTAL Memory and Speed --"
  end
end

puts "--Imported #{nol} Records--"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Import Stats
Time: 79.3
Memory: 42.51 MB
--Record Count--
Profile: 1823/2323
Course: 1723/2223
Book: 1723/2223
Import Stats
Time: 79.65
Memory: 27.88 MB
--Record Count--
Profile: 1823/2823
Course: 1723/2723
Book: 1723/2723
Import Stats
Time: 80.16
Memory: 9.91 MB
--Record Count--
Profile: 1823/3323
Course: 1723/3223
Book: 1723/3223
Import Stats
Time: 74.83
Memory: 4.19 MB
--Record Count--
Profile: 1823/3823
Course: 1723/3723
Book: 1723/3723

-- TOTAL Memory and Speed --
Time: 350.56
Memory: 102.43 MB
--Imported 2241 Records--
```

Comment: You are not cleaning up the profiles array, that might be the issue because some object memory isn’t being free up. (At least in your code example)

Comment: Oops, I mistyped my example, please review and see if you think the same thing.

Comment: Did you tried forcing the GC to run after each batch? Is the result the same? Maybe GC is not freeing memory every time when you assign the empty array (it uses incremental GC, so memory is not immediately collected)

Comment: if memory usage keeps growing, you are keeping references to objects aka leaking memory. it should not have a negative impact on performance unless your process needs to swap memory to disk. so you should separate those problems and measure individually. active-record inserts are slow, look into bulk inserts.